# Split string based on regexp without consuming characters

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I would like to split a string like the following

```
text="one,two;three.four:"
```

into the list

```
textOut=["one", ",two", ";three", ".four", ":"]
```

I have tried with

```
import re
textOut = re.split(r'(?=[.:,;])', text)
```

But this does not split anything.

Comment: Just a formulation comment it's not 'consuming characters' more like keeping delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) here instead of `re.split`:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> text = "one,two;three.four:"
>>> findall("(?:^|\W)\w*", text)
['one', ',two', ';three', '.four', ':']
>>>
```

Below is a breakdown of the Regex pattern used above:

```
(?:      # The start of a non-capturing group
^|\W     # The start of the string or a non-word character (symbol)
)        # The end of the non-capturing group
\w*      # Zero or more word characters (characters that are not symbols)
```

For more information, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what else can occur in your string, but will this do the trick?

```
>>> s='one,two;three.four:'
>>> [x for x in re.findall(r'[.,;:]?\w*', s) if x]
['one', ',two', ';three', '.four', ':']
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. Although I am getting a bit lost in understanding the command itself.